# Regex to remove or replace dates or numbers before and after slashes with empty string

Tags: c#

I have a bunch of strings and I am using a `Regex` to replace unwanted characters as needed.
However, I am having an issue with removing dates, example: 1/09/2014 1/29 or 1-29.

How can I remove those. I'm experimenting with something like this but it is way off: I can simply enter individual characters which does not work. Taken from here: [Strip Invalid Character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/844skk0h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Regex.Replace(strIn, @"[^\w\.@-]", "");
```

Sample input will look exactly like this: *Today 01/29/2014 I will go to the concert.*

*Output: Today I will go to the concert.*

Comment: Can you provide sample input and expected output?

Comment: You have to provide enough sample input so your search won't get out of control. For example, is "2014/1/29" a valid date format to you? How about "29/1/2014"? And "2014-1-29", "14/1/29", "1/29/14", "1-29", "1/29", "29th Jan", etc? Here "1-29" could capture some address, not date. If I were you, I may want to include some words after or before the date string in the pattern, like Regex.Replace(strIn, "Today [\d-\/]+", "Today "); if "Today" is always present.

Comment: Very true: I am simply looking to remove anything that resembles a date. meaning if it is before or after a Slash. So all the examples you mentioned above. Thanks my friend.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. In order to generate it I have used http://txt2re.com/ -> very handy tool.

```
string txt="Today 01/29/2014 I will go to the concert";

string re1=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
string re2="((?:[0]?[1-9]|[1][012])[-:\\/.](?:(?:[0-2]?\\d{1})|(?:[3][01]{1}))[-:\\/.](?:(?:[1]{1}\\d{1}\\d{1}\\d{1})|(?:[2]{1}\\d{3})))(?![\\d])"; // MMDDYYYY 1

var newString = Regex.Replace(txt, re1+re2, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regex

```
(?<=[0-9]{2}[\/\-][0-9]{2}[\/\-][0-9]{4}).*$|.*(?=[0-9]{2}[\/\-][0-9]{2}[\/\-][0-9]{4})
```

## [REGEX DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/107iYnKz5I)

Comment: Hello, this does not work if the date is like: `01/2014`, unless it is a full date. Thanks